# Plain Constant variables in C++

Tags: c++, constants, linkage

Plain constant variables in C++ default to internal linkage. 
Suppose If I have the following:

- I define a const variable in a header file(`const int var = 2`)
- Then I include the header in two cpp files.

If I try getting the address of that const variable (i.e `&var`) in both of the cpp files, then will those two addresses be same? Also I need a small working code to verify this fact.

I had to post this as a question because I couldn't ask it there in the comments for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328715/160206) given in this thread as I'm a newbie.

Comment: I suppose you are interested in C++. C is quite different with its rules for that. So I'd suggest to delete the C tag.

Comment: Surely this would only take a minute to test?

Comment: @Rook: No. `"a"=="a"` on my system here, but that's in fact not guaranteed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [constant variables not working in header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328671/constant-variables-not-working-in-header)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `C++` it won't be the same due to the internal linkage - these are 2 distinct objects.
In `C` it's the other way around and `const` will have external linkage, thus you will get a linkage error due to redefinition.

Comment: That is what even I think. But the answer in the link which I've mentioned says it will be the same.

Comment: That's not what's said there. Read carefully - the "same" address in that answer is because it's the same global variable. You should do some reading about the meaning of `extern` keyword and global variables.

Comment: @UchiaItachi You misread that answer. It says that if you *declare them as extern in the header* and *define them in one `.cc` file*, then you get the same address.

Comment: @icepack Oops! I read the comment wrongly. I know about the "extern" keyword but didn't catch it while reading the second point in the answer there. Moreover using the word "Plain" at the very beginning of my question kinda implies that I know about "extern"s. Anyways thanks for pointing out my blind reading. Duhh!!

Answer (score 2):

> then will those two addresses be same?

No. Because headers are included into *.cpp files during compilation, so every *.cpp that includes your header will create its own constant.

However, if you use `extern const int var;` in header and set default value in *.cpp, they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The variables will have **different** addresses. It's also possibile that if you do not reference the variable address anywhere the variabile will be substituted with his value during compilation and in the binary you will not find the variable value at all.

Comment: if it's not referenced, the variable and its value can be omitted at all from the binary, not substituted