# shared global object in google test

Tags: c++, googletest

I would like to create an object to be shared among multiple tests in multiple classes (this object is takes a long time to create).

Following [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md) guide and [this](http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/9496730/can-i-pass-parameters-to-googletest-test-function) question I came up with this:

```
static Object * model;
class MyEnvironment : public testing::Environment {

public:
    MyEnvironment(){
        model = new Object("arguments");
    }
};
```

In main, I call `::testing::Environment* const env = ::testing::AddGlobalTestEnvironment(new MyEnvironment)`. I verified that the object is created.
In another file, I try to access the created object with the following code:

```
#include "Environment1.h"

TEST(ModelTest, ReadParameter)
{
    Object *m = model ;
}
```

However, m is null. It is not explained anywhere how to implement shared objects and after hours trying some variations of this, I'm out of options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not use static with global variables - it means every module has its own copy - so file with `TEST(ModelTest, ReadParameter)` has other `model` than file with `main()`

Comment: I tried that.. but if I don't use static, I get a duplicate symbol error for model from the linker.

Comment: Read about meaning of extern keyword. You musr add it to your global variable in header, but you also have to define it in one of your cpp file

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The extern approach solved duplicate symbol issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple definition of a global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526153/multiple-definition-of-a-global-variable)