# what is the role of .LANCHOR0 in detecting multiple definitions error?

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

I got a multiple definitions error and **I fixed it** by putting the Var1 as   **static** in the header file which is common to both pet.c and bet.c. 
The following is the error log I obtained

```
libcdr.a(pet.o): In function `.LANCHOR0':  
pet.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Var1'  
build/obj/bet.o:bet.c:(.bss+0x0): first defined here  
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I checked in google **.LANCHOR0 is of type .word** in the linker script. I am not able to make out why its called a function and **what is its role** in multiple definitions error indication ?

Comment: It would definitely help if you attached source code and properly format your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple definition of a global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526153/multiple-definition-of-a-global-variable)

Comment: My Question was specific to LANCHOR0 and what is its role, what it is an how it works regards to multiple definitions error. Its not about why multiple definitions error or how to fix it. So I think its not a duplicate

Comment: I don't think `.LANCHOR0` really matters here, you still get multiple definition error on `Var1` regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.LANCHOR0` isn't a real function, it's just how GCC groups things so it can reference multiple static locations from one reference point.

Constructing a 32-bit address in a register takes multiple instructions, or a PC-relative load of a pointer from a nearby literal pool.  The compiler wants to avoid having the address of each individual static (or global) variable in literal pools near code; that would bloat things.

`.LANCHOR0`, `.LANCHOR1`, etc. are the names gcc uses for such pointers.

---

But the result of all this is that apparently variables with static storage *look* to the assembler like they're defined after a `.LANCHOR0` "function".

**There's nothing special / useful / interesting going on here as far as debugging your multiple-definitions bug.**  It's just a consequence of compiling for ARM.