# C++ multiple definition linking error with const declared in .h

Tags: c++, linker, constants

I am using some constants defined in

Constanst.h

```
#ifndef __CONSTANTS_H__
#define __CONSTANTS_H__ 

namespace A{
    namespace B{

    const int FIRST = 1;
    const int SECOND = 2;
    }
}
#endif
```

I am including this file from 2 different .cpp (A.cpp and B.cpp)

gcc version 3.2.3 is giving me "multiple definition" linking errors

I solve the problem only by including another "File.h" which includes "Constants.h" and declares the same constants as "extern"

Can someone explain why? I supposed this was an issue in C, not C++

Comment: add header guards or #pragma once

Comment: @Sugar I think that wouldn't help.

Comment: Of what type are these constants?  If you are declaring variables in a header file, they will be instantiated in each compilation unit that includes that header.  There are a number of ways around this, but usually when people _declare_ the variables (constant or not) in a header, they _define_ them in a .c file.  Your `extern` just promises the compiler that the variables are defined elsewhere, and the linker will expect to find them somewhere among the compiled objects.

Comment: @CoryKramer Are you sure?  `const` variables should have internal linkage per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2328715/4342498)

Comment: @Danh. This is C++ not C, C does not have namespaces? C++ with undeclared types called FIRST and SECOND :)

Comment: @Danh if it is linker error then absence of any include guards exactly an issue. absence of type for variable should  be compile-time error i think

Comment: @lfgtm that's the point. This code isn't valid for both C and C++

Comment: @NathanOliver Good catch, I didn't realize that distinction existed. TIL

Comment: @Danh. True, upon further inspection it is neither. o.0

Comment: @CoryKramer No problem.  Thanks for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With g++ version 4.3.4:

```
constants.h:5: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `FIRST' with no type
```

after adding type `int`, it works.

So maybe you should use a newer compiler? Use g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: The files are A.cpp and B.cpp, shouldn't it be the same using gcc or g++?

Comment: Maybe not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc. Anyway: Please try with a newer version!

Comment: sorry I use g++, but the machine is old RHEL 3, so I can't change compiler version, anyway I see the issue may depend on the compiler version