# Linking error while using structures in a separate header

Tags: c++, struct, static, constants, linker-errors

This is a simpified version of some code.

1. The `struct` is defined in `roughStruct.h`. It has a `static const char * someVar`. `someVar` is initialized outside the `struct` in the same file.
2. Another `class roughParse` (defined in `roughParse.h` and implemented in `roughParse.cpp`) intends to make use of  `roughStruct`(For the purposes of this questions it does absolutely nothing)
3. The main file `roughMain.cpp` intends to make use of the `class roughParse` to work on  `struct roughStruct`.(Again here it does nothing.)

The code doesn't compile.

4. As far I understand the error is occuring because `roughStruct` is being `include` in both `roughMain.cpp` and `roughParse.cpp`. **I need clarification here**--I am confused as to how that can be because of the next point.
5. After a lot of trial and error, the following *corrects* the error:

```cpp
//defining the const inline and not outside
 constexpr static const char *someVar="abcd";
```

or

```cpp
//using constructor to initialize and not outside
roughStruct()
    {
        someVar="abcd";
    }
```

Both approaches don't work for`const char *` replaced with `const string`.
**Why don't they?

How do you initialize a `static const string` then?**

The second approach doesn't seem ideal as structures are for holding data though I will use it if its the only way. But again, it doesn't solve the problem for strings.

But most importantly **why do these modifications remove a linking error**?

In regards to point 4, if the `roughStruct` was being included twice, it would still be in the above solutions as they don't change any `#include` directives. So point 4 is not the reason **right?**

**Code:**

The structure:

```cpp
//roughStruct.h


#ifndef ROUGHSTRUCT_H
#define ROUGHSTRUCT_H

#include<string>

struct roughStruct {
    //this is the critical thing
    static const char *someVar;
//    static std::string someStringVar;
};

const char *someVar = "abcd";


#endif //ROUGHSTRUCT_H
```

This is the parser class:

```cpp
//roughParse.h

#ifndef ROUGHPARSE_H
#define ROUGHPARSE_H

#include "roughStruct.h"

class roughParse {

    //had some code here that was implmented in roughParse.cpp
};


#endif //ROUGHPARSE_H
```

```cpp
//roughParse.cpp

#include "roughParse.h"
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//had some code here implementing roughParse.h
```

The main file:

```cpp
//roughMain.cpp


#include "roughStruct.h"
#include "roughParse.h"

int main()
{
//had some code here that used roughparse and roughStruct
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
...

add_executable(
       project
        ${SOME_DIR}roughMain.cpp
        ${SOME_DIR}roughParse.h
        ${SOME_DIR}roughParse.cpp
        ${SOME_DIR}roughStruct.h

)
...
```

**CMake Error:**

```
//ignore the line nos.
CMakeFiles/test/roughParse.cpp.o:project/test/roughStruct.h:13: multiple definition of `someVar'
CMakeFiles/test/roughMain.cpp.o:project/test/roughStruct.h:13: first defined here
```

**Env**
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
CMake: Version 3.14.3
IDE: CLion ver 2019.1.3

Comment: Every cpp that includes roughStruct.h will get its own `const char *someVar = "abcd";` instance. Looking for a dupe.

Comment: _"**How do you initialize a `static const string` then?**"_ Directly in the `struct` definition: `static const string someVar = "abcd";`

Comment: white dupe-hunting, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328671/constant-variables-not-working-in-header/2328715#2328715 which suggests I'm wrong. Running experiment.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  tried it  showed `static data member of type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>') must be initialized out of line`

Comment: @lineage What's your compiler, which standard flags used, compiler version?

Comment: Related: [Initialize static variables in C++ class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/initialize-static-variables-in-c-class)

Comment: Brain missed the class membership somehow. `const char *someVar = "abcd";` needs to be `const char *roughStruct ::someVar = "abcd";` or it's a new variable. Working back through the rest.

Comment: @ user4581301 thanks for your effort..though code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328671/constant-variables-not-working-in-header/2328715#2328715) seems to talk about `extern` use for global scopped `const` vars..i am beginner a so please explain how that helps

Comment: @ TrebledJ moving stuff out is precisely the poblem here..i want to but it doesn't link

Comment: `extern` is not needed for this use case. The short answer to your question is to place `const std::string roughStruct::someStringVar="abcd";` in one and only one cpp file and NOT in a header where it can easily be duplicated. But there's some weird nuance in the question I'm still trying to work through

Comment: Do you know what C++ Standard revision you are compiling to? It's pretty important  as the rules on `static` members and what can be defined inline have changed a lot over the past few years.

Comment: How far down the rabbit hole are you willing to go? Give `struct roughStruct { static constexpr std::string_view someStringVar = "abcd"; };` a try. For this you will need to have `-std=c++17` on the command line to force compiling to the most recent ratified standard.

Comment: @ user4581301 I am using CLion for learning c++..its using the g++ of the ubuntu system whose ver i have posted...the run config passes no flags/args to g++ ...CMake has the following build options `-j 4`..in all likelihood..its whatever the g++(stated ver) compiles in by default..i am guessing the core of the problem isn't that..i would like the code to wotk with at least c++11

Comment: sorry..build config passes no build options to cmake

Comment: I don't know the default standard of g++ 7.4, unfortunately. Agree that you want at least C++11. If this is self-directed learning or you don't have a Standard to use specified by course materials, you might as well learn the most recent. That'd be C++17. Should be a configuration page in CLion that allows you to set the dialect, and if not there's be a miscellaneous options entry box somewhere.

Comment: @ user4581301 works in c++17..without it gives `error: ‘string_view’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type  static constexpr std::string_view someStringVar = "abcd";`...whats string_view?

Comment: `std::string_view` ([doc link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)) is a new addition in C++17. It gives a lightweight wrapper around something string-ish that you typically use to to look at a portion of a larger string without having to make a copy or giving a semblance of `std::string`-like behaviour to a non-`string` . But because it's so limited and simple, it can be used in ways that `std::string` cannot. Like defining inline in a class definition.

Comment: @user4581301: `const char *someVar` is not const-qualified (the pointer), so does have external linkage.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah-ha! That makes sense. Thank you.